What TV show or movie does this quote about the four horsemen of the apocalypse come from?
Introduction
A while ago (two or three weeks tops) I was watching something on TV or similar: could have been either a movie or an episode of a TV series and didn't think much of it, but today I remembered a quote from it and I can't, for the life of me, figure out what it was that I was watching. 
Question
From what movie or Television show does the quote (or some variant close to it) below appear?

Person 1: Whereever he comes, he always has four followers. 
Person 2: So he was inspired by the bible?
Person 1: Or maybe the bible was inspired by him? 

Notes

I'm quite sure it was either urban fantasy or some form of sci-fi


I saw this in a preview at the movie theater recently. It was a preview for the new X-Men Apocalypse movie coming out.
See the trailer here at 1:12:



